# Is it possible to separate google chrome browser from default android browsers via js?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

If i go to http://zeno.github.io/mobile-detect-demo/ as via Chrome, as via browser called "Internet" on my samsung, i see that both of them are called "Chrome". But default browser has different behavior, when opening deep links.

I need to understand, when it is real chrome, provided via Google & when it is custom device provider's browser build in my web app.

Is it possible to do that via javascript? The only difference i can see, that for my default browser there is option "is samsung = true". But there are a lot of other browsers of other device manufacturers.

How could i see that user uses original Google Chrome to allow him additional features?

Comment: Isn't it usually a bad idea to do thing like this?  Do you want to return to the bad old days of writing almost separate websites for IE, Mozilla, Opera, and anything else?

Comment: which feature in Chrome do you need that is not available in the default android "Internet" browser?

Comment: @scunliffe Default android "Internet" browser fails to open deep links, and i have to workaround this with iframe. For original chrome i have to use different approach - to open those links directly.

Comment: Can you define "deep links"? I'm failing to understand why a browser (any browser) would have trouble opening a link... regardless how "deep" it might be on a site?

Comment: I am having issues with open native apps links, for example facebook `fb://profile/123456`. Some browsers (like android's default "Internet") display frustrating error, i have to workaround them.

Answer (score 0):

Create an HTML page with this content and load it in each browser:

```
<script>alert(navigator.userAgent);</script>
```

You can then "sniff" for what is different and code accordingly.

Note though that user agent sniffing is generally frowned upon, what would likely be better is to test for a feature that you need.  e.g. geolocation, indexedDB, etc. then code accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can parse the UserAgent in Javascript - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/userAgent for some documentation. Each browser sends a unique UserAgent string that will allow you to identify it. However, some browsers will pretend to be another browser (like Chrome) specifically to get around these kinds of checks.

You're better off detecting specific features rather than a browser, if you can.

See https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js for an existing JavaScript UserAgent parser.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Providing pertinent information from links in block quotes, in answers helps improve sustainability of responses - even from very good sources,